# rails5 + pumaにおけるIPアドレス制限方法について

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails5 + pumaVPS上でWEBアプリを構築しています。
検証環境において、アクセス制限をかけようとしているのですが、その方法がわからず質問させていただきます。
（おそらくconfig/environments/development.rbにホワイトリストを設定するパラメータがあると思うのですが、見つかりませんでした。。）

Answer (score 2):

@yuki-inoue さんの回答のようにネットワークレベルで制御するほうが一般的だとは思うのですが
Railsで行う方法を調べてみたところ [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) というGemを使えば希望の動作ができそうです。

https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack

上記サイトに導入方法が書かれていますが、'rack-attack`  をインストールして以下のように設定をすればホワイトリスト方式でIPを許可できるはずです。

#### config/initializers/rack_attack.rb

```
Rack::Attack.safelist_ip("5.6.7.8")
```

Answer (score 1):

IP 制限は、 rails を動かしているホストPCや、それが動いているネットワークのレベルで制御するのが一般的だと思います。 VPS ごとにやりかたは違うと思いますので、 「XXX(VPSサービス名) のインスタンスでの IP 制限のかけかた」 を調べていくのが良いと思います。